# Calculate time difference from Int in Swift

Tags: swift, time, int

I need to calculate the difference between two Int and format it to show hours, minutes. I can the function below to partially apart from the initial int difference.

Example: If i have a start Int of `0811` and then an end Int of `0912` the difference is 101. If I then take `12` from the result I should have `91`. When I use the result to convert to time it returns 1 hour and 31 mins - which is correct. However I need to somehow convert it further up the chain and then take it off to format the time correctly. This should mean the `101` should be 1 hour 1 minute.

```
func calculateTimeDifference(start: Int, end: Int, longVersion: Bool) -> String {

    let count = end - start
    let total = minutesToHoursMinutes(minutes: count)
    var formatted = ""

    if total.hours != 0 {
        formatted += "\(total.hours)"
        let amount = total.hours > 1 ? " hours " : " hour "
        formatted += amount
    }

    if total.leftMinutes != 0 {
        formatted += "\(total.leftMinutes)"
        let amount = total.leftMinutes > 1 ? " minutes " : " minute "
        formatted += amount
    }

    return String(describing: formatted)

}

func minutesToHoursMinutes(minutes : Int) -> (hours : Int, leftMinutes : Int) {
    return (minutes / 60, (minutes % 60))
}
```

Comment: Your question is so confusing. 101 minutes = 1 hour 41 minutes. Now what do you want after that?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm looking to use the difference between two Ints and if the result is in multiples of 100 then assume each 100 is an hour and the remaining is minutes.

Comment: Why don't you divide by 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't calculate the difference between two times expressed in `Int`s by subtracting them. Use the proper `Date` API.

Here, I converted the `Int`s to strings first and then parsed them using a date formatter. After that `timeIntervalSince` can tell you the difference in seconds. You just need some modulus and division to get the hours and minutes from that:

```
func calculateTimeDifference(start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"
    var startString = "\(start)"
    if startString.characters.count < 4 {
        for _ in 0..<(4 - startString.characters.count) {
            startString = "0" + startString
        }
    }
    var endString = "\(end)"
    if endString.characters.count < 4 {
        for _ in 0..<(4 - endString.characters.count) {
            endString = "0" + endString
        }
    }
    let startDate = formatter.date(from: startString)!
    let endDate = formatter.date(from: endString)!
    let difference = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
    return "\(Int(difference) / 3600)Hr \(Int(difference) % 3600 / 60)Min"
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it's late in the day here, was overthinking!

Answer (score 1):

Inherintly you are approaching this from a strange angle and causing yourself issues.

Instead of Int, which is inappropriate for storing a time, use TimeInterval which can hold a full date information, e.g.:

```
let second:TimeInterval = 1.0
let minute:TimeInterval = 60.0
let hour:TimeInterval = 60.0 * minute
let day:TimeInterval = 24 * hour
```

Then when you want to determine the time difference between two times it's very basic arithmetic.

[image: Playground example]

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 4

In Swift 4 `characters` is deprecated, so Sweepers solution in Swift 4 is

```
func calculateTimeDifference(start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"
    var startString = "\(start)"
    if startString.count < 4 {
        for _ in 0..<(4 - startString.count) {
            startString = "0" + startString
        }
    }
    var endString = "\(end)"
    if endString.count < 4 {
        for _ in 0..<(4 - endString.count) {
            endString = "0" + endString
        }
    }
    let startDate = formatter.date(from: startString)!
    let endDate = formatter.date(from: endString)!
    let difference = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
    return "\(Int(difference) / 3600)Hr \(Int(difference) % 3600 / 60)Min"
}
```